# "HTTP status 500 - Internal server error" as upload a file over the server

Tags: java, file-upload, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to upload a file over the local host server but getting and internal server error "Error instantiating the servlet class" while running it.

I have already written a code for uploading the file over the server in the UploadServelet.java class under fileupload package and have also done the mapping of the servelets in web.xml file" but still getting the error.

---

**Index.jsp**

```html
<div class="container">
    <form  method="POST" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="fname"> Select Input File: </label>                           
    <input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile"    /> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="upload" name="upload" id="upload" />

    </form>
</div>
```

---

**Web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">
    <display-name>Circedb</display-name>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadServelet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>src.fileupload.UploadServelet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServelet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Error logs:
Type Exception Report
Message Error instantiating servlet class [`src.fileupload.UploadServelet`]
Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

**Exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [src.fileupload.UploadServelet]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Root Cause

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.fileupload.UploadServelet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1363)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1186)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Comment: Are you sure UploadServelet compiled? what is its package? try removing src.: `<servlet-class>fileupload.UploadServelet</servlet-class>`

Comment: UploadServlet is compiled.. fileupload is the package which contains UploadServlet class. Tried removing the src. from src.fileupload.UploadServelet nut then tomcat server throwing an error "Tomcat server has failed to start"

Answer (score 1):

If UploadServelet compiled and uploaded correctly

You need to uodate its package by removing src.:

```
 <servlet-class>fileupload.UploadServelet</servlet-class>
```